# Add query parameter using GTM based off of a cookie

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to use Google Tag Manager to add a parameter (?test) to a page URL if a certain cookie exists for a user (ab_test = true) when the page is loading.

I need some custom javascript to do it I guess.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tested the following code and it seems like this is what you want.

```
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var cookieValue = getCookie("ab_test");

if(cookieValue === "true"){
    window.history.pushState('page', 'Title', '?test');
}
</script>
```